# Angular4 Form input file with ngForm Module

Tags: angular

The files does not send.

The file is not attached in the click event.

Via console the json is shown empty.

```
<form #form="ngForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>

<input type="file" id="file" name="file1" class="form-control" ngModel>

<input type="file" id="file" name="file2" class="form-control" ngModel>

                <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="envirArquivos(form.value)">Enviar</button>

          </form>
```

File ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'mw-compare-nfe',
  templateUrl: './compare-nfe.component.html'
})
export class CompareNFEComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  envirArquivos(form) {
    console.log(form);
  }

}
```

{"file1":"","file2":""}
empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access the `input type = 'file'` using the `ngForm` as the value for file type is not bound to `$event.target.value` but instead `event.target.files`.

So one thing you can do is :

- Update your HTML

  `<input type="file" id="file" name="file1" class="form-control" ngModel (change)="getFiles($event)">`
- Add a change event
- And listen for the change event in your JS file.

  ```
  getFiles(event) {
      console.log(event.target.files);
  }
  ```
- Now you can store these values in your variables and submit with the form.